# How to Validate entering Multiple url in one URLfield In Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-urls

I am Working with Django URLfields.

this is my model:

```
class Settings(models.Model):
    facebook_url = models.URLField(verbose_name='Facebook URL')
    linkedin_url = models.URLField(verbose_name='Linkedin URL', blank=True,null=True)
    twitter_url = models.URLField(verbose_name='Twitter URL', blank=True,null=True)
    logo_url = models.ImageField(upload_to='logo/', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = strings_settings.SETTINGS_VERBOSE_NAME
        verbose_name_plural = strings_settings.SETTINGS_VERBOSE_NAME_PLURAL
        db_table = 'settings'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.facebook_url
```

So I want that nobody will be able to add multiple url in One field. one facebook url at a time,one linkedin and one twitter.

How Can I able to do it.

Advanced Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

add the code to admin.py file:

```
class SettingsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        num_objects = self.model.objects.count()
        if num_objects >= 1:
            return False
        else:
            return True


admin.site.register(Settings, SettingsAdmin)
```

After adding one entry The add button will disappear.